# How to search for a character string that is an escape sequence with re.search

Tags: python, regex

I wrote the code to check if the escape sequence "\n" is included in the string. However, it behaved unexpectedly, so I would like to know the reason. Why did I get the result of case2?

#### Case 1

The code below worked. Since `r"\n"` (reg1) is a string consisting of two characters, `'\'` and `'n'`, I think it is correct to search for and match the target string `"\n"`.

```
import re
reg1 = r"\n"
print (re.search (reg1, "\n"))
#output: <re.Match object; span = (0, 1), match ='\n'>
```

#### Case 2

The code below expected the output to be None, but it didn't. Since `"\n"` (reg2), which is the line feed of the escape sequence, was used as the pattern, and `"\n"` consisting of two characters, `'\'` and `'n'`, was used as the target string, it was considered that they did not match. However, it actually matched.

```
import re
reg2 = "\n"
print (re.search (reg2, "\n"))
#output: <re.Match object; span = (0, 1), match ='\n'>
```

Comment: `reg2` is actaully equal to `\\ n` because here you are just using the `\\`` as just a backslash, same goes for the regex you gave in `re.search()`

Comment: `\\n` instead of `\n`. no spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct when it comes to the contents of the strings used for the regexes, but not the targets. The statement:

> `"\n"` consisting of two characters, `'\'` and `'n'`, was used as the target string,

is incorrect. The interpretation of a string is not context-sensitive; `r"\n"` is always 2 characters, and `"\n"` is always 1. This is covered in the [Python Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html):

> `r"\n"` is a two-character string containing `'\'` and `'n'`, while `"\n"` is a one-character string containing a newline.

This is more easily demonstrated with a non-control character, as a literal "\n" would be written:

Did you catch that? Let's use "þ" (thorn) instead.

### Case 1:

```
re.search(r"\u00FE", "\u00FE")
```

`r"\u00FE"` is a string with 6 characters, which compiles to the regex `/\u00FE/`. This is interpreted as an escape sequence *by the regex library itself* that matches a thorn character.

`"\u00FE"` is interpreted by python, producing the string `"þ"`.

`/\u00FE/` matches `"þ"`.

### Case 2:

```
re.search("\u00FE", "\u00FE")
```

`"\u00FE"` is a string with 1 character, "þ", which compiles to the regex `/⁠þ⁠/`.

`/þ/` matches `"þ"`.

Result: both regexes match. The only difference is that the regex contains an escape sequence in case 1 and a character literal in case 2.

What you seem to have in mind is a raw string for the target:

```
re.search(r"\u00FE", r"\u00FE")
re.search("\u00FE", r"\u00FE")
```

Neither of these matches, as neither of the targets contains a thorn character.

If you wanted to match an escape sequence, the escape character must be escaped *within the regex*:

```
re.search(r"\\u00FE", r"\u00FE")
re.search("\\\\u00FE", r"\u00FE")
```

Either of those patterns will result in the regex `/\\u00FE/`, which matches a string containing the given escape sequence.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I also misunderstood Case1 .I didn't know "The interpretation of a string is not context-sensitive".